# How to compile and run C++ by using Core linux

Tags: c++, linux

I try to compile and run C++ by using Core(11Mb)(http://tinycorelinux.net/downloads.html) but there isn't any evidence or tut about it. Please help me!!!! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a compiler, such as GCC to compile your C++ code.
And it will not be taken in any so tiny Linux installation as it weights much more than 11 Mb.

You need to consider another system to compile your code.